# Missing template Rails version: 5.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to recover the error message of the validations on my form (there must be no duplicate of ingredient) but I always have a MISSING TEMPLATE that I can not correct, I know that It's a routes problem, but I do not know which one.
I have 3 models, Cocktail Ingrédient and Dose, Dose link Cocktail and Ingredient

ERROR MESSAGE

```
MISSING TEMPLATE
Missing template cocktails/23 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/dezrt/code/Pseud0/rails-mister-cocktail/app/views"
```

doses_controller.rb

```
    class DosesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_dose, only: [:show, :destroy, :edit]

  def index
    @doses = Dose.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @dose = Dose.new
  end

  def create
    @dose = Dose.create(dose_params)
    @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:cocktail_id].to_i)
    @dose.cocktail = @cocktail
    if @dose.save
      redirect_to cocktail_path(@dose.cocktail)
    else
      # params[:dose][:cocktail_id] = @cocktail.id.to_s
      @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:dose][:ingredient_id].to_i)
      render cocktail_path(@cocktail)
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @dose.destroy
    redirect_to cocktail_path(@dose.cocktail)
  end

  private

  def dose_params
    params.require(:dose).permit(:cocktail_id, :ingredient_id, :quantity, :description)
  end

  def set_dose
    @dose = Dose.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

cocktails_contronller.rb

```
class CocktailsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cocktail, only: [:show]

  def index
    @cocktails = Cocktail.all
  end

  def show
    @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
    @dose = Dose.new
    @dose.cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
    @ingredient = Ingredient.new
    @ingredients = Ingredient.all
  end

  def new
    @cocktail = Cocktail.new
  end

  def create
    @cocktail = Cocktail.create(cocktail_params)
    if @cocktail.save
      redirect_to cocktail_path(@cocktail)
    else
      @cocktail = Cocktail.new(cocktail_params)
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def cocktail_params
    params.require(:cocktail).permit(:name)
  end

  def set_cocktail
    @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

views/cocktails/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Cocktail X</h1>
<h2>Voici la listes de tout nos cocktails</h2>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Nom du cocktail : <%= @cocktail.name %></h3>
  <ul>
    <h4>Ingredients : <% @cocktail.doses.each do |dose| %></h4>
    <li><%= dose.ingredient.name %> : (<%= dose.quantity %><%= dose.description %>)</li>
    <%= link_to dose_path(dose), method: :delete do %>
        <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>


<%= link_to "Retour aux cocktails", cocktails_path %>

<div class="container">
  <h4>Ajouter des ingrédients</h4>
  <%= simple_form_for [@cocktail, @dose] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :ingredient_id, collection: @ingredients %>
  <%= f.input :quantity, label: 'Quantité', error: 'La quantitée est obligatoire' %>
  <%= f.input :description, label: 'Description', error: 'La description est obligatoire' %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root "cocktails#index"
  resources :cocktails do
    resources :doses, only: [:new, :create, :edit]
  end
  resources :doses, only: :destroy
end
```

rails routes

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                      Controller#Action
              root GET    /                                                cocktails#index
    cocktail_doses POST   /cocktails/:cocktail_id/doses(.:format)          doses#create
 new_cocktail_dose GET    /cocktails/:cocktail_id/doses/new(.:format)      doses#new
edit_cocktail_dose GET    /cocktails/:cocktail_id/doses/:id/edit(.:format) doses#edit
         cocktails GET    /cocktails(.:format)                             cocktails#index
                   POST   /cocktails(.:format)                             cocktails#create
      new_cocktail GET    /cocktails/new(.:format)                         cocktails#new
     edit_cocktail GET    /cocktails/:id/edit(.:format)                    cocktails#edit
          cocktail GET    /cocktails/:id(.:format)                         cocktails#show
                   PATCH  /cocktails/:id(.:format)                         cocktails#update
                   PUT    /cocktails/:id(.:format)                         cocktails#update
                   DELETE /cocktails/:id(.:format)                         cocktails#destroy
              dose DELETE /doses/:id(.:format)                             doses#destroy
```

Thanks you for your help !

Comment: When do you have that error?

Comment: When I want to add an ingredient that already exists in the list of cocktail ingredients. I have added a validations to prohibit this case, so I can not get the error message on my form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Missing template cocktails/23 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],
>   :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby,
>   :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *
>   "/home/dezrt/code/Pseud0/rails-mister-cocktail/app/views"

This line `render cocktail_path(@cocktail)` is the reason for the error. `render` loads a view. So the input to the `render` normally should be name of the file, in your case `show` view of the `cocktails`. Changing it to `render 'cocktails/show'` should fix the error.

Also you seems to be confused between `render` and `redirect_to`. I suggest you to read [*render vs redirect*](http://tosbourn.com/difference-between-redirect-render-rails/)